# Parts in running text but not in TOC

Tags: sectioning

Is there a way to include the full `\part` in running text (including "Part xxxx", but but not include it in the TOC?

Comment: In any case that would depend on the class being used. So as always please provide a small minimal self contained example such that we know what we are dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
% tocpartprob.tex  SE 580856
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
%\arabic{tocdepth}  % returns 2 in this case

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}} % no Part in ToC
\part{A Part}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}} % restore default ToC entries

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

The first `\addtocontents...` sets the printed ToC entries to be higher than `\Part` while the second one resets the printed ToC entries to be as normal.

Comment: Thansk Peter, working flawlessly.